# cannot run node command without using npm

Tags: node.js, npm

I am working on a new node project in windows machine.

In my ***package.json*** I've set test script:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "cucumber-js test"
  },
```

If I run the command `> npm run test` it works properly, but if I run `> cucumber-js test` I get the following error:

```
cucumber-js : The term 'cucumber-js' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify 
that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ cucumber-js test
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (cucumber-js:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Is there any explanation? How can I resolve it?

Comment: You need to have cucumber-js installed globally in order to be able to execute it from the command line like so. Any other way you need to execute through npm in order to access the project's dependencies

Comment: When you run a command from `scripts` with `npm`, it automagically knows to look in `/node_modules/.bin` for it. However, just trying to run `cucumber-js` from the command line won't work. You could either install it globally or provide the exact path `node /node_modules/.bin/cucumber-js` maybe

Comment: using exact path in windows style `.\node_modules\.bin\cucumber-js test` has resolved the problem. Thank you @Nick

Comment: @lromano97 Global installation gave me some extra error, but it does not matter, because as mentioned before, the exact path worked.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments the problem is resolved by providing the exact path: `.\node_modules\.bin\cucumber-js test`